# Can't type text into table cell when form is protected

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I created several tables in a Word document to act as a form for users to fill out. In some cells I added check boxes and dropdown lists for people to select options from.

When I click on the Protect form button the check boxes and dropdowns become active; however, I can't type anything in the other cells. If I click in an empty cell it automatically moves to the next checkbox.

When I unprotect the form then I can type in the empty cells but then checkboxes and dropdowns become useless. I know that the user can double click on the checkbox and then manually select to have it checked, but they can't do this with the dropdowns.

What do I have to do to allow the user to type in responses to the tables cells and also select answers from checkboxes and dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

One way I discovered is to add breaks above and below the cells that contain checkboxes and/or dropdowns.

Then specify which section to protect under Tools, Protect Document. Choose Forms then Sections and check those breaks that have checkboxes or dropdowns.

This won't work though if you have cells that need to be edited that are adjacent to cells with checkboxes, etc.